# How does "casting without paying mana cost" work with additional costs?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Cards with cascade like [Maelstrom Wanderer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMaelstrom%20Wanderer%5d) say "...You may cast it without paying it's mana cost." Does this include mana costs added from sources like [Sphere of Resistance](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSphere%20of%20Resistance%5d), or would it always be cast for free, regardless of additional costs?

Comment: This is an alternative cost, and Total cost = (Mana cost or alternative cost) + (additional costs and cost increases) - (cost reductions)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must pay additional costs separately, so you would still have to pay {1} for Sphere of Resistance.

Casting without paying is an alternate cost:

> 117.9. Some spells have alternative costs. An alternative cost is a cost listed in a spell's text, or applied to it from another effect, that its controller may pay rather than paying the spell's mana cost. Alternative costs are usually phrased, "You may [action] rather than pay [this object's] mana cost," or "**You may cast [this object] without paying its mana cost.**" Note that some alternative costs are listed in keywords; see rule 702.

Additional costs are added separately from alternate costs:

> 117.9d If an alternative cost is being paid to cast a spell, any additional costs, cost increases, and cost reductions that affect that spell are applied to that alternative cost. (See rule 601.2f.)

Comment: Ah, so "cast without paying mana cost" falls into an alternate cost type, treated as 0?

Comment: @ShadowZ. Right; it's something that you can pay rather than paying the normal cost. It just happens to be that "nothing" is what you pay.

Comment: Look at a spell like Fling, the spell does not work if you don't pay the additional cost, since the sacrificed creature sets a value in the effect.